# Is there a way other than with JS to accomplish table row highlighting with CSS in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-tables

I'd like to add row highlighting on hover using on CSS that will work in Internet Explorer. I have tried the following:

```
#tableId tr:hover td { background-color:#f00; }
```

This seems to work in Opera, Firefox, and Safari, but not in IE.

Is there a solution or is the only solution JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some versions of IE (specifically, IE6, though :hover is buggy in IE7) do not support :hover, which means there's simply no way to accomplish row highlighting without JavaScript.

Just to be technically correct - IE6 does support :hover, but only on anchor tags, so you can't target table rows.

Comment: +1 -- it's impossible to prove a negative, but in this case.... yeah, you can.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Lew is correct. IE6 only supports hover on anchor elements but I know from experience IE7 will support hover on what you plan on doing. To get IE6 to do the hover I used `csshover.htc`. I can't remember where I found it, but if you google "csshover.htc" you'll get a bunch of links (example: [whatever:hover](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html)). I do know that it was free and open source so you can also just rip it off [this site I made](http://www.propertypress.co.nz) :).

EDIT: I'm a dumbass. The link I provided is the exact one I used :)

EDIT2: This is a hover working in IE7 for the exact same situation you have (doesnt implement IE6 fix however) [New Truck Search Directory](http://www.newtrucksearch.com.au/Article/Content/Directory)